# symfony upgrade to 3.4 mplementing DataCollectorInterface

Tags: symfony

I have recently upgraded symfony and get I

> mplementing
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\DataCollectorInterface"
>   without the "reset()" method is deprecated
>   can some one give me solution how I can solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a bundle, with a class implementing DataCollectorInterface without method reset()... You can look in your code at classes implementing DataCollectorInterface. Chances are the class is in your vendor directory and this is a third party bundle.

If so check this course on how to update such bundle:

https://codereviewvideos.com/course/upgrade-symfony-3-to-symfony-4/video/fixing-third-party-bundle-deprecations

Comment: thanks a lot , I am using FOS\ElasticaBundle\DataCollector\ElasticaDataCollector , this is where I get deprecation  warning

Comment: but I dont know which version of bundle should I upgrade its really confusing , in the link there is an example for guzzle upgrading :(

Comment: why don't you try to upgrade FOS\ElasticaBundle to the newest version compatible with your other settings ? You can check requirements for 5.0.3 here : https://packagist.org/packages/FriendsOfSymfony/elastica-bundle